# OnSensorChanged() is not triggering for the Step detect sensor

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I recently started working with android and I wanted to program my own Pedometer app that counts how many steps I have taken. Sadly somehow the onSensorChanged() method isn't called. I made sure my phone has the sensor and I also made sure that everything else is working fine (registering a listener, creating a SensorManager and a Sensor) and everything seems to be working fine. I have als added
`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"`  in the android manifest since another post stated this is needed. Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{

    Button btnReset;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor stepSensor;
    private boolean isStepSensorAvailable;
    private TextView txtSteps, txtCheck;
    private int stepCounter;
    private List<Sensor> deviceSensors;  //bugfixing

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();

        if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) != null)
        {
            stepSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
            txtCheck.setText("Sensor was found, stepsensor is now " + stepSensor.getName());
            isStepSensorAvailable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            txtSteps.setText(getString(R.string.txt_step_sensor_not_available));
            isStepSensorAvailable = false;
        }


    }

    private void initialize() {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        txtSteps = findViewById(R.id.txtSteps);
        txtCheck = findViewById(R.id.txtCheck);
        stepCounter = 0;
        btnReset = findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
        btnReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        txtSteps.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    /**
     * Checking for available Sensors
     */

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) != null)
        {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, stepSensor, sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            txtCheck.setText(txtCheck.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "listener registered!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) != null)
        {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, stepSensor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor == stepSensor)
        {
            txtCheck.setText(txtCheck.getText() + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Sensorevent was triggered!");
            stepCounter = (int) (stepCounter + event.values[0]);
            txtSteps.setText(String.valueOf(stepCounter));
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (event.sensor == stepSensor)
```

with

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it this way but sadly it is still not working. Could there be any problem where my app doesn't have the needed authorization to use the sensor?

Comment: you can check if your device has sensor using `context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR)`

Comment: I have checked this before but I also checked using your method just to be sure and my phone does have the required sensor, the "SAMSUNG Step Detector Sensor" to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-feature
   android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter"
   android:required="true"/>
  
<uses-feature
  android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector"
  android:required="true"/>
```

If you use Android 10 or later, you also need to add the following permission:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is not asking for permission..
I'm only putting it on the Manifest.
To get permissions...

```
// GET PERMISSIONS
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, 19);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So in my case - I had to go into Settings -> App Permissions and then give my Android app the Physical Activity permission. Might be different on your phone, but for anyone wondering why the code looks perfectly fine and it's still not capturing pedometer data, this might be the reason if all else seems fine.